# Finding max sum by removing elements from either head or tail of list with added value based on their order of removal

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

We are given a list L of integer numbers along with a list K of integer numbers. The goal is to maximize the sum with the constraint to remove one element at a time from either the start or the end of the list L and this element will be multiplied by the value K[i] (assuming i is the order of removal).

This procedure will go on until we have used all values of list K.

One example would be:

```
L = [5,11,2,3,22,1]    
K = [1,3,2]
```

The optimal solution would return a sum of `1*1 + 3*22 + 2*5`.

I am thinking about using dynamic programming and considering an array `dp[i][j]` that would return the maximum sum for the list `L[i:j+1]`. In that way, I could think of the recurrence as:

```
dp[i][j] = max(dp[i+1][j] + L[i] * (?), dp[i][j-1] + L[j] * (?))
```

Though, I am not sure how I could fill those question marks and how to populate the array to get the answer `dp[0][n]`.

Comment: why isn't the max `1*5 + 3* 22 + 2 * 11`?

Comment: @Kenan You first have to remove the 1 before 22 can be reached.

Comment: @MichaelButscher then how is the `11` reached?

Comment: @C.Nivs Oh, right.

Comment: Similar to what @C.Nivs is stating, you would remove `5` to get to `11`. Maybe supply another example?

Comment: but if he removes 5 he needs to multiply with 5, at least thus he wrote in the task @Kenan

Comment: @ncica exactly, I think OP needs to clarify a bit more to outline the rules of the problem

Comment: Why not simply take `(?) = K[i+n-1-j]` ? `i+n-i-j` corresponds to the number of elemtns already removed

Comment: I totally agree, the task is wrong or the given example is wrong @C.Nivs

Comment: Yes, the example I gave is wrong. Sorry for that. I edit the post to contain a better example.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
L = [5,11,2,3,22,1]
K = [1,3,2]

def solution(L, K):
    if len(K) == 0:
        return 0

    sol1 = K[0] * L[0] + solution(L[1:], K[1:])
    sol2 = K[0] * L[-1] + solution(L[:-1], K[1:])

    return max(sol1, sol2)

print(solution(L, K))
```

Prints:

```
77
```

---

If you want to see what was multiplied, you can try this:

```
def solution(L, K):
    if len(K) == 0:
        return 0, []

    s1, p1 = solution(L[1:], K[1:])
    s2, p2 = solution(L[:-1], K[1:])

    sol1 = K[0] * L[0] + s1
    sol2 = K[0] * L[-1] + s2

    if sol1 > sol2:
        return sol1, p1 + [(K[0], L[0])]
    else:
        return sol2, p2 + [(K[0], L[-1])]


print(solution(L, K))
```

This prints:

```
(77, [(2, 5), (3, 22), (1, 1)])
```

Comment: What would be the time complexity of such a solution? Wouldn't it be something like O(2^n)?